# Можно ли выяснить, взаимодействует ли программа с какими-то локальными сервисами на ПК или нет?

Tags: windows, поиск-программ, мониторинг

В общем, есть некоторая программа.

Мне нужно выяснить обращается ли она при работе к каким-то локальным сервисам или нет. Иными словами: делегирует ли она при работе какие-то отдельные задачи на другое ПО, т.е меж процессорное взаимодействие.

Собственно вопрос:

А есть ли какие-то утилиты, которые позволят промониторить внешнюю активность программы или нет?

Comment: попробуйте искать по словам `sandbox resource monitor`

Answer (score 4):

С помощью [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) можно мониторить взаимодействие софта с файловой системой, регистрами. Также можно посмотреть инфу по потокам/процессам и сетевую активность.

Comment: А точно взаимодействие между процессами там отображается?

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы под "взаимодействием" подразумеваете возможность видеть буквально, какие там данные ходят?

Comment: В идеале да, но мне бы было бы достаточно самого факта.